# Google Cloud Project Service Accounts

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am using a Google Cloud Project to automate the creation of some users inside of our organization. I have been using some API's that are hosted using the Google Cloud and have had no problem authenticating and using the API's, however I am not sure if I should be using a service account for this. I am currently using the Google Drive API, the Google Admin SDK(Directory API), the Sheets API, and the Docs API to create some accounts and manage an error log.

What I am asking is, should I be creating a service account to use the API's or is my own personal Google Workspace account okay for creating these? Is there a site/video/something that can guide me in the right direction if I do need to create a service account. I personally would rather have all of the automation using a service account for authentication, but the only videos and tutorials I found on using the service accounts are trying to use resources pertaining to Cloud Computing and service accounts that are impersonating other service accounts.

Comment: Review Domain Wide Delegation. That will explain how to use a Google Cloud service account with Google Workspace. https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a [Service Account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/best-practices-for-using-and-managing-service-accounts#choosing_when_to_use_service_accounts) is the best course of action for security reasons when you are the one giving authorization and authentication to your organization.

It is identical to granting access to any other identity to allow a service account access to a resource. For instance, suppose you only want an application that runs on Compute Engine to be able to generate items in Cloud Storage.

As a result, instead of managing each and every one of your users, you may limit and manage service accounts, assign certain roles to specific users or groups, and keep track of them because several service accounts can be created in a project.

Since you use Google Workspaces, I also advise you to read the shared documentation posted in the comments by @John Hanley.